# Android read in a .txt file packaged with app

Tags: java, android, file, embedded-resource

I want to be able to read in a file, **myFile.txt**, that I ship with my app, either in the assets folder, the res/raw folder, where ever, it does not matter.

BUT! I do not want an InputStream of that file... I want to be able to do something like:

```
while ((reader = is.readLine()) != null) { ... }
```

I've searched around and found stuff that was close but not really what I'm looking for..

Thank you for any help.

EDIT - some code I was trying:

```
InputStream in = this.mCtx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myFile);
Reader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF8"));
```

(now what? The Reader class doesn't have a readLine() method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change

```
Reader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF8"));
```

to

```
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF8"));
```

`BufferedReader` has a `readLine()` method. You're unnecessarily upcasting to Reader and losing the additional features.

Comment: awesome thanks! EDIT - I just noticed I'm required to throw an exception for this... Do you know under what circumstances this might fail?

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/package-summary.html - you want to look at the descriptions for exceptions thrown in the constructors for both InputStreamReader and BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1):

use BufferedReader instead of Reader for definition.

```
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF8"));
```

Bufferedreader has readline method but not reader

Answer (score 1):

You can store the file in sdcard and specify its location in "file_path" in below code:

```
File selectedFile = new File("file_path");
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
```

And then

```
while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
        //Do Stuff Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new BufferedInputStream(is));
```

**Edit:** Sorry - my fault. Just stick with the BufferedReader.
Opening a ressource can be done with

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/org/example/res/my_file.txt");
```

See [Class#getResourceAsStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29))

Comment: How could I create the "is" object? From the InputStream? I'll update the OP with some code I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

Use these **steps to get it done....**

```
File f = new File("/sdcard/MyFolder/MyFile.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String str = new String();

while((br.readLine())!=null){


   sb.append(br.readLine());  


 }

str = sb.toString();
```

Comment: This will discard new lines as `str` will have no none. This probably isn't a good idea... either process each line directly or save the new lines for later processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like that:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open("yourfile")));
```

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) buffer.append(line).append('\n');

And in your assets dir simply put your file without .txt extension.
Hope this help you.